# mdadm reassemble from spare disk crashed during resync

Tags: linux, mdadm

The server crashed while raid-1 /dev/md2 with /dev/sda3 + /dev/sdb3 was resyncing from /dev/sdb3 to /dev/sda3. sadly, /dev/sdb was lost completely due to a hardware fault.

I'm now left with only /dev/sda3 which is part of /dev/md2 but not suitable.

```
mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose
[..]
mdadm: /dev/sda3 is identified as a member of /dev/md2, slot 2.
mdadm: No suitable drives found for /dev/md2
```

Output of examine:

```
mdadm -E /dev/sda3
/dev/sda3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : e5249c1c:02d996e3:776c2c25:004bd7b2 (local to host rescue)
  Creation Time : Wed May  4 13:48:24 2011
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 730202368 (696.38 GiB 747.73 GB)
     Array Size : 730202368 (696.38 GiB 747.73 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 2

    Update Time : Fri Jun  7 22:06:35 2013
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1
       Checksum : d56f21ea - correct
         Events : 13242378


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     2       8        3        2      spare   /dev/sda3

   0     0       0        0        0      removed
   1     1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
   2     2       8        3        2      spare   /dev/sda3
```

**Is there any option to reassemble md2 from sda3 alone, making it somehow suitable again?**

(Of course, there's the alternative to mount it as ext3, copy files to spare disk and recreate the raid, but I'd like to reuse the already existing disk if possible.)

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, then _neither_ disk will have a consistent view of your data, and your best course of action will be to restore from backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the metadata knows several steps of "Does this disk belong to an array?". I am not familiar with those details; I just assume that it is similar to the dirty flag of a file system. When you take a new disk into an array then it is probably marked as spare until it is completely in sync. After that the metadata is probably changed to "is a full member of the array".

The best solution would indeed be to create a new array and restore from backup.

If you do want to give the disk a chance (knowing that the "truncation" will get the file system into really bad mood) then you should create a new array from this disk:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md2 --metadata=0.90 --raid-devices=2 --level=raid1 /dev/sda3 missing
```

Comment: thanks a lot, works like a charme! that was exactly what I was looking for!